# Make inner div 100% width of body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the child `div` width to be 100% of the body.

CSS

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:red;
}
#inner {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background:blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45thwhkj/1/)

I'm using `position:relative` for parent `div` and the `position:absolute;` solution is not working. How can I do this? Js solutions are acceptable.

Comment: `#inner` is constrained by its parent, which is `#container`, so setting it to 100% will only make it as wide as its parent. Place it outside of `#container` and it should work.

Comment: I know it but it must be in the #container this is problem

Comment: We need to see more of your markup, and do you have a link to your existing project?

Comment: Sorry but it's wordpress theme and codes are relatively js and php.

Comment: Is there a link that we could see?

Comment: I'm working on localhost now. I'm working on js solution like this.
1- Find browser width
2- Find inner div offset left
3- Give a negative left value to inner div offset left and make inner div width browser width + offset left value

This is working. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/45thwhkj/3/)

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin-top:30px;
}
#container {
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:red;
}
#inner {
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
```

You just have to remove the `position:relative` from the container div and everything will work as expected

**AND**

I dont think there is a need for writing JS for this as this can be just obtained using CSS.

Comment: it's no longer an "inner" div like this.  He's wanting a div inside another div to be the width of the body.  this does not solve that probelm (EDIT: downvote removed now that the answer has been updated)

Comment: Sorry @RyanWheale I mis understood the question.Thanks for pointing out..I've edited my answer..Could you please remove the downvote..

Comment: I must use the position:relative; for #container and this solutions is not working. Thank you

Comment: you should remove that position:relative for #container.That will work..See the fiddle..

Comment: I must use the position:relative; for #container and this solutions is not working. Thank you

Comment: I have so complicated code block this is simple version. I must use to position relative. How can I fix it with js?

Answer (score 1):

In html, if you have an element inside of a container while using % it will respect the containers boundaries.

So, no sure why Lal was downvoted. but his solution works.

Especially because your container is relative, the absolute container will be absolute to the container and not the body itself. You could remove position: relative; on the container and it will work that way, but it depends on what you want to do.